# How can you view the values of Eigen/unsupported/Tensor objects in a debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, eigen, eigen3, debuggervisualizer

I have a c++ program that uses a lot of tensor and matrix arithmetic. I chose the c++ `Eigen` library for this purpose, even though the `Tensor` module is not officially supported by the maintainers, because of all the functionalities it offers and because established libraries like tensorflow are also utilizing it.

I am currently always printing the tensor objects when I want to look at the values, since at least in vscode you cannot directly view the tensor values in the debugger:

[image]

After doing some research, I found the [Native Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=webfreak.debug) extension, which I thought could allow users to visualize the values of datastructures such as `Eigen::Tensor` objects, by adding a file, e.g. called `eigen.natvis`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="Eigen::Tensor&lt;*, *, *, *&gt;">
    <DisplayString>{{ Dimensions={NumDimensions} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <ArrayItems>
        <Direction>Row</Direction>
        <Rank>NumDimensions</Rank>
        <IndexListItems>
          <Value>dimensions()[i]</Value>
        </IndexListItems>
        <ValuePointer>data()</ValuePointer>
      </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

and then modifying the `.vscode/launch.json` by adding the line

```
"setupCommands": [{"text": "Natvis.add %workspaceFolder%/eigen.natvis"}]
```

But unfortunately this did not have any effect. Did I do something wrong when utilizing the Native Debugger extension, or is there a different way or a different ide that allows you to directly view the values of `Eigen` objects? Simply doing

```
std::cout << u_tilde_padded << std::endl;
```

prints out

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

to the console, is there a way to accomplish this through the debugger as well?